# Dynamically create intents in Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am thinking about the following scenario:

The user queries the Dialogflow agent with something there is no intent defined for yet, however, due to the nature of the application, there should be an intent for that query. Sort of like the userbase is extending the agent simply by issueing queries.

Is this reasonable to achieve? If not, is it possible to get anything close to that, or an alternative way?

I had the following two scenarios in mind for realizing something like this:

1. Use the fallback intent for catching unmatched queries and match it in the code: Any query which can't be matched to an intent is given to the fallback intent anyway. One could write these queries into a database in that intent, and then later on, again in the fallback intent, the query could be matched against the database (using something like percentage similar by comparing the strings), and the query could be answered from the database. The problem I see here is exactly this matching, as it seems inefficient to not use Dialogflow for what it is actually for.
2. Again use the fallback intent, but create intents via the Dialogflow API. The Dialogflow SDK provides a method of creating an intent from a given query. The problem I see here though, is that there won't be an intent defined in my fulfillment functions code for the intent which was created via the API, so again, this would go to the fallback intent.

Comment: FWIW, what you describe in the first option is exactly the scheme I use in an Actions SDK project. Once I bench marked the parsing code and found that I could parse(tens of?)  _thousands_ of queries in a second I quit worrying about performance especially in light of the fact that there is at minimum one less network hop in rolling your own. To put it another way, it's not less efficient but it is more complicated. I'm convinced the extra complication is a net gain for me.

Comment: @WilliamDePalo sounds interesting. Could you provide some more details on the parsing?

Comment: I rolled my own in custom parser in plain-vanilla JavaScript. Nothing fancy. You might be able to use something like this https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise or maybe Google's Parsey McParseface if you wanted to write the JavaScript wrapper.

Comment: @WilliamDePalo This is quite an amazing lib, thank you!